# SQL select statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I got a Table which has two fields: Point, and Level,
with some sample data as follows:

-----------------------
Point   |    Level
-----------------------
10      |    Level 1
20      |    Level 2
30      |    Level 3
40      |    Level 4

Suppose that there is a user who has 25 points,
to find the Level in which this user is in, the Select statement I used was:

```
Select Level from Table where Point < 30 AND Point > 20;
```

But the Select SQL ststament is a hard-copy one 
where you can see the ponts 30 and 20 are fixed. 
I want to alter the Select statement so that the new SQL Select 
statement can be applied to all users with different points, 
but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you may want a QUARTILE type result?  what is the objective if you do not code a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Level FROM Table WHERE Point<=25 ORDER BY POINT DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or

```
SELECT Level FROM Table WHERE Point>=25 ORDER BY POINT LIMIT 1
```

Depends on what level the user has for 25 points (2 or 3).

Comment: shouldn't it be SELECT Level FROM Table WHERE Point <= 25 ORDER BY POINT DESC LIMIT 1?

Comment: @Maxem, You are right, I updated the answer. I tested it now.

Comment: -1 the answer should not be coded to 25 as a hardcoded value.

Comment: @Randy: It isn't hardcoded. In that place, he can put his variable from the program. It would be hardcoded if it contained 20 or 30.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   case 
      when point between 20 and 30 then 30
      /*optionally You can add more Cases */
      /*when some other then again other */
      else point
   end as point
from Table
```